# Complaints filed about "Pati Sudharo Sansthan"?

Tags: plot-explanation, hello-darling

In the 2010 Hindi movie, [Hello Darling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_Darling), how come the victims of "Pati Sudharo Sansthan" never filed any police complain about it? It is surely illegal and should not be operating at all.

How were they even able to operate without a lot of legal consequences?

Comment: This sounds more like a plot hole question, but i'm not familiar with this movie so i can't be 100% sure.

Comment: @DForck42 Yes, its just a plot hole and movies like this is full of them

Comment: Such questions are supposed to ask about bollywood movies. Just enjoy such movies by keeping the brain aside.